# Upload image data then reference object Swift Combine pattern?

Tags: ios, json, swift, file-upload, combine

It's a common scenario to want to upload image data to something like S3 and then write the reference object to a DB. I have been learning Apple's Combine framework and am stuck trying to come up with a pattern to accomplish this.

Let's say I have an object that holds the info about my image and a publisher to start the pipeline.

```swift
struct ObjectWithImage: Encodable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let imageData: Data
    let imageURL: String

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case imageURL
    }
}

extension Publishers {
    static let uploadObjectQueue: PassthroughSubject<ObjectWithImage, Never> = PassthroughSubject<ObjectWithImage, Never>()
}
```

I also have a legacy image uploader that would be using the S3 SDK or something. The definition is kept short and contrived for the example.

```swift
struct LegacyImageUpload {
    //https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-future
    public func upload(imageData: Data) -> Future<Bool, Error> {
        let future = Future<Bool, Error> { promise in
            self.upload(data: imageData) { (p_error) in
                guard let error = p_error else {
                    return promise(.success(true))
                }
                return promise(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        return future
    }

    private func upload(data: Data, completion: @escaping((_ error: Error?) -> Void)) {
        //Code not here to keep example short
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

I have a struct that could live at the `AppDelegate` which would be subscribing to the publisher.

```swift
struct ObjectUploadPipeline {

    var subscription: AnyCancellable

    init() {
        self.subscription = Publishers.uploadObjectQueue.tryMap({ (object) -> Future<Bool, Error> in
            let legacyImageUplaod = LegacyImageUpload()
            return legacyImageUplaod.upload(imageData: object.imageData)
        }).map({ (future) -> Bool in
            //How do I switch back to the origional object so that I can now upload the Encoded JSON or write to my DB?
            return true
        }).sink(receiveCompletion: { (pipelineCompletion) in
            switch pipelineCompletion {
            case .finished:
                break
            case .failure(_):
                break
            }
        }, receiveValue: { (endValue) in

        })
    }
}
```

Then finally tie it all together.

```swift
struct ObjectGenerator {
    init(numberOfObjects: Int) {
        for item in 0..<numberOfObjects {
            let object = ObjectWithImage.init(id: UUID(), name: "Object \(item)", imageData: Data.init(), imageURL: "path/to/image")
            Publishers.uploadObjectQueue.send(object)
        }
    }
}

let uploadPipeline = ObjectUploadPipeline()
let objectGenerator = ObjectGenerator.init(numberOfObjects: 10)
```

How to I ensure that the image uploading succeeds first? If it succeeds how to I get the next operator to know about the `ObjectWithImage` so I can encode it as data and then send it up to my cloud? Preferably using the built in `URLSession` publisher?

I like combine and see the power but am having trouble stringing all the concepts together to complete this pipeline.

Comment: Part of the answer is likely going to be highlighted by what you want to happen when it does fail... if it's all inline, the whole subscriber pipeline would be cancelled by a failure. If you put the upload inside a flatMap, then you create a sort of secondary pipeline where you can handle the failure, and then return what you want down the ongoing pipeline. It sounds similar to how you handle errors when you have a constantly flowing set of events and don't want an error in one to cancel the whole thing. (ref: https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-continual-error-handling)

Comment: FWIW - I find it easier to think about how to arrange combine pipelines if you frame the question/problem as starting and being driven by the subscriber and then working back up the chain to how you source things, since that aligns with how combine operates and specifically propagates demand (and errors).

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things about Combine is that it forces us to think about what we want to do when errors happen. We can ignore them, but we have to be explicit about ignoring them. In your question, you haven't addressed what you want to do with a failure from the `Future` returned by `upload(imageData:)`. Do you also need to know the `ObjectWithImage` in that case?

Let's assume that in the success case, you want to output the `ObjectWithImage` (so you can use it downstream in the database loader), and in the failure case, you want to output both the `ObjectWithImage` and an `Error` (so you can display a cryptic error message). For the failure case, let's make a type that combines the `ObjectWithImage` and an error:

```
extension ObjectWithImage {
    struct UploadError: Error {
        var object: ObjectWithImage
        var error: Error
    }
}
```

Your `upload(imageData:)` method's `Output` is `Bool`, but it only ever outputs `true`. We should use `Void` instead of `Bool` to make it clear that the specific value of the output doesn't matter:

```
struct LegacyImageUpload {
    public func uploadImageData(_ data: Data) -> Future<Void, Error> {
        return Future { promise in
            self.upload(data: data) { (error) in
                if let error = error { promise(.failure(error)) }
                else { promise(.success(())) }
            }
        }
    }

    private func upload(data: Data, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        fatalError("real code omitted")
    }
}
```

Now we'll extend `LegacyImageUpload` with a method that takes an `ObjectWithImage` directly and uploads its image. On success, it outputs the object so that we can use it downstream. On error, it outputs an `UploadError` so that we can properly handle the error downstream:

```
extension LegacyImageUpload {
    public func upload(_ object: ObjectWithImage) -> AnyPublisher<ObjectWithImage, ObjectWithImage.UploadError> {
        return uploadImageData(object.imageData)
            .map { object }
            .mapError { ObjectWithImage.UploadError(object: object, error: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Note that, because we changed the upstream output type from `Bool` to `Void`, we can write `.map { object }` instead of `.map { _ in object }`.

We can chain this into the database loader if the database loader takes an `ObjectWithImage` as input, and has the same `Failure` type of `UploadError`.

Let's assume we upload to the database using a `DataTaskPublisher`. We need to map  `DataTaskPublisher.Failure` (which is really `URLError`) back to `UploadError`. We'll also want to map the normal output back to the input object. So it probably looks something like this:

```
struct DatabaseLoader {
    enum Errors: Error {
        case badStatusCode(Int)
    }

    private func request(for object: ObjectWithImage) throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
        return request
    }

    public func upload(_ object: ObjectWithImage) -> AnyPublisher<ObjectWithImage, ObjectWithImage.UploadError> {
        return Just(object)
            .tryMap(self.request(for:))
            .flatMap({
                URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
                    .mapError { $0 as Error }
            })
            .map { $0.response as! HTTPURLResponse }
            .flatMap({
                return $0.statusCode == 200
                    ? Result<Void, Error>.Publisher(())
                    : Result<Void, Error>.Publisher(Errors.badStatusCode($0.statusCode))
            })
            .map { object }
            .mapError { ObjectWithImage.UploadError(object: object, error: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

We now have all the pieces necessary to implement the full pipeline. BUT! If any one object can't be uploaded, we **don't** want to emit a failure to our subscriber! Emitting a failure ends the subscription, but maybe an error isn't fatal and we can try uploading more objects. So we need to turn failures into normal outputs. We'll use the standard Swift `Result` type as the output, like this:

```
let objectsToUpload = PassthroughSubject<ObjectWithImage, Never>()
let legacyUploader = LegacyImageUpload()
let databaseLoader = DatabaseLoader()

let uploadTicket = objectsToUpload
    .flatMap({
        legacyUploader.upload($0)
            .flatMap { databaseLoader.upload($0) }
            .map { Result<ObjectWithImage, ObjectWithImage.UploadError>.success($0) }
            .catch { Just(Result.failure($0)) }
    })
    .sink(receiveValue: {
        switch $0 {
        case .success(let object):
            // Update UI to tell user that object was uploaded successfully.
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            // Show a cryptic error message telling the user
            // that error.object wasn't uploaded because of error.error.
            break
        }
    })
```

Comment: Wow! What an incredible example. Lot's to digest here. I like the use of the Swift Result type on a pipeline like this. On your extension of LegacyImageUpload I didn't realize you could take a value from outside a pipeline and reference it. I guess no memory considerations here as declarative is supposed to be magical?

Comment: “Declarative” and “magical” are not well-defined terms, so I can't tell you which it is. `ObjectWithImage`, as defined in your question, is a value type. That means the copy capturing by `.map { object }` cannot be modified by side effects.

Comment: Well things are not always well defined. I was playing around with your example to understand a little better. I edited your final result to be a little more verbose in hopes of helping someone understand the whole pipeline a little faster. Thanks!

Comment: I feel that all the explicit parameters and types obscured the important parts of the code. I would prefer that you post your own answer in this case instead of editing mine. On stackoverflow, you are allowed to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ok, I disagree with your first assertion but agree with your second one.